# Use String variable in InetAddress.getByName() in Android

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I want to connect to an IP using
`ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.116");`
Now,the issue is that this IP keeps changing due to DHCP and because the device needs to connect to different routers on different occasions. So, I added a textbox dialog at the beginning to allow the user to enter the IP manually.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("DEVICE IP");
alert.setMessage("Enter DEVICE IP");
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    device_ip = input.getText().toString();
    Log.d("MY_LOGS", "IP SET TO " + device_ip);
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "DEVICE IP: " + device_ip ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
alert.show();
```

Now, the issue is that after I get this IP from the user as a `String`, I am doing this

```
try {
        ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName(device_ip);
        Log.d("MY_LOGS",  "ipaddr SET TO: " + ipaddr.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MY_LOGS",  e.getMessage());
}
```

However, in this case, the app is not sending the message to the IP.

What could be the difference between manually setting the IP as a string and entering the IP as a String variable?

LOGS FOR VARIOUS CASES:

---

Logs for `device_ip`:

`IP SET TO 192.168.1.116`

---

Logs if manually entered IP:

`ipaddr SET TO: 192.168.1.116`

---

Logs if using String variable for IP:
`ipaddr SET TO: localhost`

Comment: Well what does the log show? It's useful to include some trailing value in the log so that you can see where the string *ends* as well... and log `ipaddr` as well, so you can see what it's been fetched as.

Comment: I'm sorry, give me one moment.

Comment: I did log `ipaddr`. In case of manual entry, it shows the IP as given. In case of entering the IP as string, I simply get `localhost` as `ipaddr` value.

Comment: Right, so you don't need to go as far as sending the message. You only need to focus on getting the right value for `ipaddr`. Now, you still haven't included any logs of the value of `device_ip`...

Comment: @JonSkeet, just added. Please check.

Comment: As I said before, you should add a trailing value so you can see where the string *ends*. Of course, you should also be able to do this in the debugger. Fundamentally, there's no difference between the string "192.168.1.116" as entered by a user or hard-coded, so long as it really *is* that string - which means it *isn't* that string, so you need to find out in what way it isn't.

Comment: I'm using the debugger and a breakpoint and I can see that the String `device_ip` is ending properly. I've even added a basic string comparison check to see if they are the same. (they are). But when I run the app, I get the error as shown in the logs.

Comment: Well if two strings are equal, I find it hard to believe that one would work and the other not. If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - tricky with Android, I know - then we could help you more, but at the moment it *sounds* like some kind of misdiagnosis...

Comment: It's a bit hard to demonstrate the program since there are other hardware involved. Are there any other ways to elucidate the problem to you so that you can help?

Comment: Is that other hardware required in order to demonstrate the problem in converting a String to an InetAddress? I doubt it - part of diagnosing problems is limiting their scope. I suggest that you start a new project with just a single activity with a textbox and a button, which calls `InetAddress.getByName` when you click the button. You don't need *anything* else to demonstrate the problem here.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and get back to you. Much thanks. That other hardware is basically running a Python server that listens to requests from my android app. So unless that is running, how would I know if my message is getting received properly? The whole issue is that if I enter the IP manually, the Python server receives the message properly. If I use the textbox method, it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68032/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-jon-skeet).